# Moving Objects Between Scenes Using A List (MoveGameObjectToScene) - Beginner Question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# so this is a fairly beginner level question. I have created a project from YouTube videos to create a basic game using Mapbox. Having completed the base project I now want to complete some of the ‘challenges’ from the end to continue my learning.

I want to be able to pass an object from one Unity scene to another. The object in this case is a ‘droid’ which, when clicked on, loads a new scene where the droid can be captured. The scene where the droid is captured currently uses a pre-placed droid prefab as a placeholder. What I would like to happen is for whatever droid is clicked on in the 'world' scene, to be actually passed into the new scene (meaning that droids using different prefabs can be loaded into the new scene rather than just the pre-placed droid prefab which is currently there).

I have listed out the code snippets from different scripts which form the journey of clicking the droid (Droid.cs), through to adding the clicked object to a list and moving it to the chosen scene (SceneTransitionManager.cs).

The SceneTransitionManager.cs script is attached to objects in both the ‘world’ scene where the droids exist and are clicked on, and in the ‘capture’ scene where I want the droid object to be passed to.

I am struggling to find the correct syntax to retrieve the droid object from the list (probably because I am still a beginner!), I think using a list from a different script is probably making it harder in my head than what it actually is.

I believe this code belongs in the CaptureScene.cs script as this is the scene where I want the object which is moved scenes to be moved to (this script is attached the same object as the SceneTransitionManager.cs script). Once I can retrieve this object from the list I assume the next step would be to assign this to a SerializedField which is attached to an empty game object.

Here are the segments from the scripts which are relevant to moving the objects between scenes (there are also GameManager and Singleton scripts but I haven't included them as I do not think they are relevant to this query):

**Droid.cs**

```
public class Droid : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnMouseDown() 
    {
        PocketDroidsSceneManager[] managers = FindObjectsOfType<PocketDroidsSceneManager>();
        
        foreach (PocketDroidsSceneManager pocketDroidsSceneManager in managers)
        {
            if (pocketDroidsSceneManager.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                pocketDroidsSceneManager.droidTapped(this.gameObject);
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

**PocketDroidsSceneManager.cs**

```
public abstract class PocketDroidsSceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public abstract void playerTapped(GameObject player);
    public abstract void droidTapped(GameObject droid);
    
    public virtual void droidCollision(GameObject droid, Collision other)
    {
        
    }
}
```

**WorldSceneManager.cs**

```
public class WorldSceneManager : PocketDroidsSceneManager
{
    public override void droidTapped(GameObject droid)
    {
        List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
        list.Add(droid);

        SceneTransitionManager.Instance.GoToScene(PocketDroidsConstants.SCENE_CAPTURE, list);
    }
}
```

**PocketDroidsConstants.cs**

```
public class PocketDroidsConstants
{
    public static string SCENE_WORLD = "World";
    public static string SCENE_CAPTURE = "Capture";
 
    public static string TAG_DROID = "Droid";
}
```

**SceneTransitionManager.cs**

```
public class SceneTransitionManager : Singleton<SceneTransitionManager>
{
    private AsyncOperation sceneAsync;
 
    public void GoToScene(string sceneName, List<GameObject> objectsToMove)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadScene(sceneName, objectsToMove));
    }
 
    private IEnumerator LoadScene(string sceneName, List<GameObject> objectsToMove)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
 
        SceneManager.sceneLoaded += (newScene, mode) =>
        {
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene(newScene);
        };
 
        Scene sceneToLoad = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(sceneName);
        foreach (GameObject obj in objectsToMove)
        {
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(obj, sceneToLoad);
        }
 
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**CaptureScene.cs**

```
public class CaptureSceneManager : PocketDroidsSceneManager
{
//what code goes here to retrieve the droid from the list
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Dont destroy is what you want
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: Thanks Mistergreen. I think I should have included more context in the original question. I have many 'droid' objects in the world scene which are spawned at random and I only want the one I click on to passed through to the next scene.

I might be misunderstanding but I do not not think that DontDestroyOnLoad alone fits this use case. Or I could just be using it incorrectly.

If I include 'DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);' in a script attached the droid objects (the ones I want to pass between scenes), it gets applied to all droid objects so that when one is clicked they're all passed.

Comment: Or you can use a singleton variable to save the droid and respawn the droid in a new scene.

Comment: So is using MoveGameObjectToScene not the recommended way for this use case? I was hoping that it would be relatively straight forward to retrieve an object in another script using this?

Comment: MoveGameObjectToScene could work.